# Calendar Bundle from Symfony2 not showing up in my page with include

Tags: symfony, twig

I was able to post the calendar using this tutorial https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle but I can not inject this page into another either with `{{include}}` or with `{ Extends}` and `{block}`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/adesignscalendar/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/adesignscalendar/css/fullcalendar/calendar.css') }}" />
<!----javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/adesignscalendar/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/adesignscalendar/js/fullcalendar/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/adesignscalendar/js/calendar-settings.js') }}"></script>
<!---JSrouting-->
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
{% include 'ADesignsCalendarBundle::calendar.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: You'll find it more helpful not to post links outside of Stack, but to post the content that is problematic for you. Work over the problem to understand where your failure occurs, then pinpoint your question to receiving help with the related code.

Answer (score 0):

Is important about this problem the position of the links must be in the layout.html.twig or in this example in base.html.twig.

In the documentation the calendar-bundle only say the requirement of installation FOSJsRouting but they not say configuration this links is obligatory:

For this job I work with Symfony 3

Regards